# Error while trying to assign test to EditText using binding

Tags: java, android

The Toat shows the content but when trying

```
Toast.makeText(this, getIntent().getStringExtra("ARTICULO"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        
binding.edtArticulo.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("ARTICULO").trim()) ;
```

Getting this error:

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.widget.EditText com.example.scanapp.databinding.EditActivityBinding.edtArticulo' on a null object reference in method 'void com.example.scanapp.EditActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle)'

Already check the Intent contents, all is fine.

Complete Class code:

```
public class EditActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditActivityBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_activity);

        Toast.makeText(this, getIntent().getStringExtra("ARTICULO"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        binding.edtArticulo.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("ARTICULO").trim()) ;

}
}
```

Comment: We are gonna need more of the code about the binding. Where you set it/clear it and where do you try to setText.

Comment: That'll be all the code so far: public class EditActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditActivityBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_activity);

        Toast.makeText(this, getIntent().getStringExtra("ARTICULO"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        binding.edtArticulo.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("ARTICULO").trim()) ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the binding, it is empty/null. You are not using/inflating it.

```
setContentView(R.layout.edit_activity);
```

That's the old regular way. Replace it with:

```
binding = EditActivityBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
setContentView(binding.root);
```

Comment: Thats it.... there are no emoticons here, just imagine a man covering his face....